# AutoUpdater.NET Кто использовал?

Tags: c#, winforms, update

Необходимо сделать авто обновление для программы созданной в winforms. Нашел решение [тут](http://autoupdaterdotnet.codeplex.com/documentation), но по внедрению в проект, плохо работает, либо скачивает новую версию в папку "Загрузки" либо вообще ничего не происходит. Может быть есть кто то, кто использовал эту библиотеку, подскажите так и должно быть, библиотека просто скачивает не заменяя исходный файл или я что то не так делаю?

Comment: А не хотите посмотреть в сторону [*ClickOnce*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/t71a733d.aspx)? Все же "родная" технология от MS.

Comment: @DmitryD. Хочу но не нашел нормального мануала по установке, я новичек в c# и без хорошего примера мне тяжеловато. Плюс я где то читал что если пользователь не админ на компе, то с ClickOnce могут быть проблемы.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [NAppUpdate](http://www.code972.com/blog/2012/06/55-the-philosophy-behind-nappupdate). Так же он доступен через NuGet. Показалось проще и надежнее чем AutoUpdater.NET, в поставке есть демо-примеры дабы было проще разобраться.