# Как реализовать фоновое автообноаление программы?

Tags: c#

Как реализовать обновление, как например у античита Faceit. При запуске проверяется на наличие обновлений, если есть, то скачивается, если обновлений нету, то запускается дальше. Может есть где то тема? Желательно консольное приложение. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: сверху поиск. В него вводишь "автообновление программы С#".

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/565479/213987